# Mapping similar objects in two images

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

As a part of a larger project I am doing, I want to find the displacement and scale difference between the similar objects in two images. These objects are only of basic shapes.

I am currently in trouble identifying a way to map 1 in the left image to 1 in the right image and 2 in the left image to 2 in the right image. My requirement is to map the most similar shapes in terms of location in and the size

I am very new to image processing and currently learning, so any resource would be welcome which answers the above question.

[image]

Comment: What prevents 1 in the left image from being mapped to 2 in the right one?

Comment: My requirement is to map the most similar shapes. 1 in the left image is most similar to 1 in the right image in terms of the location and the size. Thanks for the questions to clarify. I will update the question with these details as well.